# is there is way to solve this error: error: Dao class must be annotated with @Dao public abstract interface SleepDatabaseDao

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I just made a project for practice and now when I use Database class it shows error and when I remove that class then it works

I tried to make a database in my project and made the database class before then that it was  working when I used the database class now it shows error and then if I remove the database class it works

```
@Database(entities = [SleepNight::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class SleepDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val sleepDatabaseDao: SleepDatabaseDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: SleepDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): SleepDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            SleepDatabase::class.java,
                            "sleep_history_database"
                    )
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
build failed    2 s 346 ms
Run build   2 s 300 ms
Load build  2 ms
Configure build 122 ms
Calculate task graph    83 ms
Run tasks   2 s 89 ms
null    
C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker-starter-code  
app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out 
app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/database/SleepDatabaseDao.java  
error: Dao class must be annotated with @Dao
public abstract interface SleepDatabaseDao {
                ^

> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use for you database [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html), than check this documentataion:

... and [DAO](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html)

You have to annotate your class/interface with @Dao

```
@Dao
interface MyDao 
{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertUsers(vararg users: User)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did :     `abstract val sleepDatabaseDao: SleepDatabaseDao` is wrong.
Yo should do:
`abstract fun sleepDatabseDao: SleepDatabaseDao`

Reason: You are not calling the interface @Dao